# Select 3 columns as distinct from 5 selected columns in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Input table Data:

```
|Col1  |Col2    |Col3   |Col4   |Col5
|----  | ---    |---    |---    |---
|AA    | 11     |9009   |1      |1
|AA    | 11     |9009   |2      |2
|BB    | 22     |8888   |1      |1
|CC    | 33     |7777   |1      |1
|CC    | 33     |7777   |2      |2
|DD    | 44     |6666   |1      |1
|EE    | 55     |5555   |1      |1
|EE    | 55     |5555   |2      |2
```

This should be saved to a target table, like below, because col1, col2, col3 are defined with composite primary keys:

```
Col1   |Col2   |Col3   |Col4  |Col5
-----------------------------------
AA     |11     |9009   |1     | 1
BB     |22     |8888   |1     | 1
CC     |33     |7777   |2     | 2
DD     |44     |6666   |1     | 1
EE     |55     |5555   |2     | 2
```

How can I use distinct on the first 3 columns, but select all 5 columns?

I have seen other examples for selecting one distinct column. Can anyone please help on this example?

Comment: Which of the values for the "other" two columns do you want? Rows in a relational table have no defined ordering, and without an `ORDER BY` clause the database can choose to return rows in any order it cares to.

Comment: Any one row is fine for the other 2 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to order the rows for each combination of the first three columns - this is the job of analytic functions, and specifically in this case `row_number()`. Then just pick the "first row" from each "group" (or "partition" in the terminology of analytic functions). Something like

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
from   ( select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,
                row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3 order by null) as rn
         from   input_table
       )
where  rn = 1
;
```

`order by null` means "order by whatever you want, I don't care, just order the rows within each partition."

Answer (score 0):

Another variant is to use GROUP BY, and aggregate functions on the ancillary columns. For example:

```
select col1, col2, col3, max(col4) as column4, min(col5) as column5
from input_table  
group by col1, col2, col3;
```

Comment: This may pick max(col4) and min(col5) from different ROWS in the input data. The OP seems to want to pick one row (ANY row) as-is from the inputs.